# Is there a way to import an ArgoUML model into Modelio?

Tags: interop, uml, argouml, modelio

I'm trying to migrate an ArgoUML file to Modelio. According to my understanding, both support XMI, but somehow this still doesn't work. When I export my ArgoUML data to XMI, Modelio won't import it, I get the following error:

> Failed: file content is not recognized as a valid model.

So.. is there a way to get around this? ArgoUML is version 0.34, Modelio is version 3.1

Answer (score 3):

In fact the formats supported by both tools are different. 
ArgoUML exports in UML1.4/XMI 1.1 format and Modelio imports in UML2.x/XMI2.x format (adopted in 2005...), that's why your ArgoUML exports are not recoginized by Modelio import.

Obviously one workaround would be to transform UML1.4/XMI1.1 in, at least, UML2.1.1/XMI2.1... I just google "transform UML 1.4 2.1" and I found the following [site](http://www.baptisteautin.com/projets-personnels/php_uml/convertisseur-de-fichier-xmi/lang/en/) but I did not test it!!!

Comment: In addition to what Red Beard mentions, UML 1.x has no standard way of storing diagrams, so you'll only get the basic model data from any conversion and will need to recreate the diagrams.

Comment: In fact only latest UML specification (2.5) defines a storing format diagram until now OMG had define a DI (Diagram Interechange) specification which does not seem to be implemented by so much tools...

Comment: Thank you, @RedBeard! It does migrate classes, but the diagrams as such, as well as deployment components etc are not there. I'm not entirely sure that it's the site's fault just yet however.

Comment: Diagrams will be lost I am pretty sure of that.. for the rest I will take a look just for my pleasure